# Uploading .html file to S3 Static website hosted bucket causes download of .html file in browser

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have an S3 bucket with 'Static Website Hosting' enabled. If I upload a html file to the bucket via the AWS Console the html file opens successfully. If I upload the file using the AWS CLI the file is downloaded rather than displayed in the browser why?

The first file is available here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/test-bucket-for-stackoverflow-post/page1.html

The second file is available here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/test-bucket-for-stackoverflow-post/page2.html

I uploaded the first file in the AWS Console, the second was uploaded using the following command:

```
     aws s3api put-object --bucket test-bucket-for-stackoverflow-post  --key page2.html --body page2.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second file is downloaded because of its 'Content-Type' header. That header is:

```
Content-Type: binary/octet-stream
```

If you want it to display, it should be:

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

Try adding `--content-type text/html` to your `put-object` command.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object.html

Comment: Thank you that was it, I changed my s3api call to 

       aws s3api put-object --bucket test-bucket-for-stackoverflow-post  --key page3.html --body page2.html --content-type text/html

Comment: If you use `aws s3 cp` that will attempt to guess the content type for you. It will also try to upload the file as efficiently as possible.